# Why do some processes end with the letter "d"?

Tags: process, filenames, terminology

Some Linux binaries end with a "d", for example
sshd, httpd, ppd, etc.

Why is this so?

Comment: `man sshd`, check the "NAME" section (first one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**d** at the end of some process means **daemon**.

**Deamon** means processes which works in background and services works in background.

**Background** here means that you don't have direct access to it and they aren't waiting for you! If you set that a service comes up after system booting it will run automatically.

A bit more technically:

> Daemons are usually instantiated as processes. A process is an
>   executing (i.e., running) instance of a program. Processes are managed
>   by the kernel (i.e., the core of the operating system), which assigns
>   each a unique process identification number (PID).
>
> There are three basic types of processes in Linux: interactive, batch
>   and daemon. Interactive processes are run interactively by a user at
>   the command line (i.e., all-text mode). Batch processes are submitted
>   from a queue of processes and are not associated with the command
>   line; they are well suited for performing recurring tasks when system
>   usage is otherwise low.
>
> Daemons are recognized by the system as any processes whose parent
>   process has a PID of one, which always represents the process init.
>   init is always the first process that is started when a Linux computer
>   is booted up (i.e., started), and it remains on the system until the
>   computer is turned off. init adopts any process whose parent process
>   dies (i.e., terminates) without waiting for the child process's
>   status. Thus, the common method for launching a daemon involves
>   forking (i.e., dividing) once or twice, and making the parent (and
>   grandparent) processes die while the child (or grandchild) process
>   begins performing its normal function.

Two good references:

http://www.linfo.org/daemon.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207724/72402:

A binary can be named whatever the author wants to call it but it is common practice to name a binary with a d at the end to *indicate* that it is a daemon process/invoker.